# Scrapy: Predefined parse method in Pycharm

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

I learning `Scrapy`, and using `Pycharm verison 2021.3.1 Community Edition`. When creating the `parse()` method for the `Spider` class, Pycharm suggests defining the `parse()` method with two parameters (`response`) and  (`kwargs`):

```py
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        pass
```

However, according to the the [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html), the `parse()` method is defined with one parameter (`response`).

```py
    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```

### Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with Pycharm's predefined `parse()` method? Are there any cases where the `parse()` method would pass two arguments?
2. If there is something wrong with this predefined `parse()` method, how can the `suggestion snippet` be edited?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you are a beginner, `def parse(self, response):` would work. You can ignore PyCharm's warning or use `def parse(self, response, **kwargs):`

Once you learn more, you will feel the need of passing data from one callback function to another. This functionality can be achieved using `cb_kwargs`.

For example, see this code:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    current_page = response.css('.footer::text').get()
    product_link = response.css('.prod::attr(href)').get()

    yield scrapy.Request(product_link, callback=self.parse_product,
        cb_kwargs={'page':current_page}


def parse_product(self, response, page): #this callback receives additional param
    self.logger.log(f'Current page :{page})
```

I hope this makes sense.

You can see the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=cb_kwargs#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) for more details.